# If every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic and normal then is $G$ finite cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, general-linear-group

Ok, this may look familiar. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992306/if-every-proper-subgroup-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-is-cyclic-then-g-is-cy) you find a very close question, but not using the normal part of it. This is a exercise from a Brazillian book, Paulo A. Martin's "Grupos, Corpos e Teoria de Galois" (the translation is quite easy). It says:

> If every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic and normal then is $G$ finite cyclic?

The answer is, probably, no. The book puts a sugestion, wich is to set $G$ as $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, with generators
$$
a = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{matrix} \right), b= \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
and study its subgroups. Well, this seems quite hard. I've found [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82749817.pdf) paper online, but it doesn't help, since this is supposed to be a easy/medium level question. There is another example of group that we can use as an counter example? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The counterexample you mention is the quaternion group $Q_8$ which I would have thought is well-known. The required property follows easily from the fact that it has a unique element of order $2$. There are also infinite abelian examples: the groups $C_{p^\infty}$ of $p^n$-th roots of unity for primes $p$, if you think they are any easier!

Comment: Btw every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic and normal but $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very elementary counterexample, namely the Kleinian $4$-group
$$
G=C_2\times C_2.
$$
Every proper subgroup has order $1$ or $2$, and hence is cyclic. Since $G$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal. Of course $G$ is not cyclic.

This example already has been given at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992306/if-every-proper-subgroup-of-a-finite-abelian-group-g-is-cyclic-then-g-is-cy), where normality holds, since $C_p\times C_p$ is abelian.